# How many input pixels influence output pixel in an FCN type architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

Let's say I have 8 back to back convolutional layers with zero padding such that the input and output dimensions are the same. There are no max-pooling layers between the layers. All the layers use a 3x3 filter. I want to calculate how many pixels influence each of the output layers. How do I go about doing this?

I know that if there is only 1 layer, then each of pixel in the output is influenced by 9 pixels from the input. If there are 2 layers, then I'm guessing there would be 25 pixels influencing each pixel in the output. This is because if the second layer runs a 3x3 filter over layer 1, then those 9 pixels correspond to a 5x5 grid in the input layer. Am I properly calculating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are calculating it pretty much correctly.

Have a look at [A guide to receptive field arithmetic for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807) and [A guide to convolution arithmetic for deeplearning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285) for formulas how to compute sizes of things in convnets including more complicated cases like non-unit strides etc.

Also, note that theoretical receptive field is in practice not the same as the actual one. Have a look at the paper [Understanding the Effective Receptive Field in Deep Convolutional Neural Networks (Luo et al., 2016)](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~wenjie/papers/nips16/top.pdf) for some examples.

Comment: These references are fantastic, this should be upvoted a ton.